# Create folders using values from Excel

Tags: vba, excel

this place has saved me numerous times so here I am again. I'm trying to use Visual Basic to create folders from an excel spreadsheet - I've managed to find this simple solution on the net which works to an extent - however I'd like to use values from adjacent cells also:

```
Sub MakeFolders()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim maxRows, maxCols, r, c As Integer
Set Rng = Selection
maxRows = Rng.Rows.Count
maxCols = Rng.Columns.Count
For c = 1 To maxCols
r = 1
Do While r <= maxRows
If Len(Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
MkDir (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c))
On Error Resume Next
End If
r = r + 1
Loop
Next c
End Sub
```

I'm guessing it would end up looking something like...

```
(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Rng(r, c) & Rng(r, c).Offset(0, 12))
```

But I am honestly clutching at straws, any help would be fantastic.

Comment: *"this place has saved me numerous times"*... Great, but it looks like you never accepted any answer to your previous questions :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is intended to create separate folders for each of the selected cells and it works fine. Do you rather want to create 1 separate folder for each of the selected rows by combining the values of all columns within that row as folder name?

To clarify, let's say:

 - A1 = `xx1`, B1 = `xx2`

 - A2 = `yy1`, B2 = `yy2`

The existing macro will create 4 folders: `xx1`, `xx2`, `yy1`, `yy2`

If you rather want 2 folders `xx1xx2`, `yy1yy2`, you may make a few changes, like this:

```
Sub MakeFoldersForEachRow()
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim maxRows, maxCols, r, c As Integer
    Dim s As String
    Set Rng = Selection
    maxRows = Rng.Rows.Count
    maxCols = Rng.Columns.Count
    For r = 1 To maxRows
        s = ""
        For c = 1 To maxCols
            s = s & Rng(r, c)
        Next c
        If Len(Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & s, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
            MkDir (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & s)
            On Error Resume Next
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks so much. I've managed to adapt it to add in spacers also so it's worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: glad to know it helped:)