# Create folders using 2 column values from Excel

Tags: vba, directory, space

So I need to make a whole bunch of folders from a spreadsheet.
I have in column A the Surname and in Column B the name of a person, I need to generate folders based on this.

I have [found a bit of code that someone else posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44711430/create-folders-using-values-from-excel/66106770#66106770), that works, but I need to add a space between the name and surname in the created folder.
The original poster said that they did manage to add a space, but never indicated how.

```
Sub MakeFoldersForEachRow()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim maxRows, maxCols, r, c As Integer
Dim s As String
Set Rng = Selection
maxRows = Rng.Rows.Count
maxCols = Rng.Columns.Count
For r = 1 To maxRows
    s = ""
    For c = 1 To maxCols
        s = s & Rng(r, c)
    Next c
    If Len(Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & s, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
        MkDir (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & s)
        On Error Resume Next
    End If
Next r
```

End Sub

Comment: I cannot understand what you want accomplishing using the above code. Do you need a folder name obtained from concatenation of A1 with B1 (space in between), A2 with B2 and so on?

Comment: If you only have 2 columns dispense with the `c` loop and use `s = Rng(r, 1) & " " & rng(r,2)`.

Comment: @FaneDuru that is correct... that is what I need.
And from your answer it seems to work fine

Comment: is there a way that it can be set to the selected columns only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code:

```
Sub createFoldNamesFromTwoColumns()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, fldName As String, i As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your necessary sheet
 lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
 For i = 1 To lastR
    fldName = sh.Range("A" & i) & " " & sh.Range("B" & i)
    If Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & fldName, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & fldName
    End If
 Next i
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

I could see now your last request, meaning to process the selected columns:

```
Sub createFoldNamesFromTwoSelectedColumns()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rngSel As Range, C1 As Long, lastR As Long, fldName As String, i As Long
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 Set rngSel = Selection

 If rngSel.Columns.count <> 2 Then MsgBox "You must select two columns!": Exit Sub
 C1 = rngSel.cells(1).Column: Stop
 
 lastR = sh.cells(sh.Rows.count, C1).End(xlUp).row
 For i = 1 To lastR
    fldName = sh.cells(i, C1) & " " & sh.cells(i, C1 + 1)
    If Dir(ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & fldName, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & fldName
    End If
 Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: @Carl Visagie: Did you find some time to test the above code? If tested, didn't it do what you want?

Comment: I tested the first set of code, will test the new one soon, just a bit swamped with other things

Comment: there seems to be a error with the code on this line:
C1 = rngSel.Cells(1).Column: Stop

but using the previous code I got the end result i needed. It will just be more efficient and versatile if it did it for selected columns only

Comment: @Carl Visagie: Glad I could help! 1. We here, when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. Our main goal is to make people learning. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works. 2. Not an error on that line... The `Stop` command stops the code on that specific line, to give you the possibility to check the result when try debugging. I only forgot to delete it, but I thought it should be simple to delete or comment it. I also thought that my previous code is the best way.

Comment: yeah, so the previous code does the job.
but still, having it do it for selected only would be so much better for a few reasons.
thank you for your time and help